# How to stop XMLReader throwing Invalid XML Character Exception

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader, invalid-characters

So I have some XML:

`<key>my tag</key><value>my tag value &#xB;and my invalid Character</Value>`

and an XMLReader:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)))
{
     while (reader.Read())
     {
         //do my thing
     }
}
```

I have implemented the CleanInvalidCharacters method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399075/remove-all-hexadecimal-characters-before-loading-string-into-xml-document-object) but as the "&#xB" is not yet encoded it doesn't get removed.

The error is being thrown at the reader.Read(); line with exception:

> hexadecimal value 0x0B, is an invalid character.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have XML -- you have some string that sure looks like XML but unfortunately doesn't really qualify. Fortunately you can tell `XmlReader` to be more lenient:

```cs
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml), new XmlReaderSettings { CheckCharacters = false }))
{
     while (reader.Read())
     {
         //do my thing
     }
}
```

Note that you will still end up with XML that, when serialized, might produce problems further down the line, so you may wish to filter the characters out afterwards anyway as you're reading it.

Comment: How would I filter out values further down the line? Would I do it in the while loop. Encode it as xml and remove invalid characters?

Comment: You can use the `CleanInvalidCharacters` approach mentioned in your original post on the text nodes, element and attribute values (as you encounter them in the while loop, indeed). It will work now since the characters have already been decoded.

Comment: perfect , i was trying too many things in last 2 hours without any luck